# How to call function through form action with php

Tags: php, html

I want to call a function which deletes my cookies, so I don't get any issues with that.
After deleting the cookies, it should return to my main HTML page.

```
echo '<tr><td colspan="5"><form method="" action="returnMain()"><button type="Submit">Zurück</button></form></td></tr>';
```

That's where I want to call my function. So if the button is clicked, it should call the function returnMain, delete the cookies and go back to my HTML page.

How am I able to call the function through php?

At the moment, the only thing that happens is that if I click the button, the function name is added to my URL which doesn't work at all.

Comment: PHP operates on the server side, meaning that it cannot affect anything stored on the client, such as cookies—unless you are referring to PHP server session cookies. You will have to use JS for that—bind a submit event listener to the form, and delete the cookie appropriately. I suppose `returnMain` is a JS function?

Comment: No, it's a php function actually. I created the cookies through php using `setcookie("name", "value", time()+3600);` and in the specific function, the code is like `setcookie("name", "", time()-3600);`

Comment: Then what you can do it set the action of the form to the page itself: i.e. `action="get" method="#"`, and at the top of the script of the page, before any output is sent, you check for the cookie and if present, modify/delete it as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Please add form like below code

```
<form method="" onclick="returnMain()" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Comment: How should I put the `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"` in my code when my button already is within ``<?php ... ?>` ?
Should it then be just like `actino="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ?

Comment: I tried it like that, but I'm getting an error (unexpected String 'PHP_SELF') since I put the whole form already in an `echo '<form.... />';`, what am I doing wrong or how can I solve that?